# Get error message react native to build release app.apk "error typeerror : cannot read property 'result code ' of undefined"

Tags: java, android, react-native

"error typeerror : cannot read property 'result code ' of undefined"

[image: Error screen]

When i run it with command "npm react-native start " it very ok but when i trying build it to apk with command "  ./gradlew assembleRelease" and run on android it get error

i don't know what happend this appear with me